# Correct way to check if a X509Certificate is a root ca

Tags: ssl, x509certificate, x509

I've a list of X509Certificates and I would like to check if they are a CA and in this case if they are a root CA. So I'm using this code:

To check is this a CA

```
private boolean isCa(@NotNull X509Certificate certificate) {
        if (certificate.getBasicConstraints() != -1 && certificate.getKeyUsage()[5] == true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Per documentation, I should only verify the getBasicConstraints but I also check that the certificate can be use to sign (checking for keyCertSign )

I also would like to check if the certificate is a root CA. So I compare the issuer distinguished name and the  subject distinguished name to verify that they are equals. In this case, I assume this is a root CA

```
try{
X500Principal idn = certificate.getIssuerX500Principal();
X500Principal sdn = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal();
certificate.verify(certificate.getPublicKey());
return idn.equals(sdn);
}
catch(Exception e){
return false;
}
```

If this method of validation correct?
Update: Add the self signed verification

Comment: `X509Certificate.getKeyUsage()` will return `null` if the extension is not present in the certificate, and your code will throw a null pointer exception in that case. In terms of code robustness I would be tempted to wrap all the checking code in a `try-catch` block and return `false` if any exception is thrown. X.509 is quite complicated, the RFC 5280 rules are quite complicated, and the Java X509Certificate class is quite complicated. Rather than check for every edge case just simplify and let exceptions do the heavy lifting. You should also verify that the certificate is self-signed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to verify that the cert is self-signed (apart for comparing the issuer and the subject.

Comment: Okey, I got it ```certificate.verify(certificate.getPublicKey());```